# how to make radio button value based dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two radio buttons, first one is male, 2nd one is female.

If user click that male radio button I need to show some list of male names with submit button . If user click female radio button I need to show only list of female names with submit button.

When I open this page it should show only two radio buttons based on selection only dropdown should come with submit button.

For example user select male, in that dropdown list user selected raju, agil, gowri, when user click that submit button I need to show in console gender with selected male names.

Someone help me out to move forward I have enclosed my code :

```js
$(function() {
$('#male').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('#female').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.gender = [{
        name: "Male"
    }, {
        name: "Female"
    }];
    
    $scope.submit =function()
 {
 alert($('#male').val());
 alert($('#female').val());
 }
    
    
}
```

```css
<style type='text/css'>
    .multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 20px;
}
 </style>    
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>
```

```html
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Select your Gender</p>
 <form data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in gender">
            <label>{{person.name}}
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.favoriteBeatle"
                name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required="required"/>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
 <div style="padding:20px">

<select id="male" multiple="multiple">

<option value="gowri">Gowri</option>

<option value="agil">Agil</option>

<option value="raju">Raju</option>

<option value="viswanath">Viswanath</option>

<option value="duruwan">Duruwan</option>



</select><br /><br />

<input type="submit" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>
<div style="padding:20px">

<select id="female" multiple="multiple">

<option value="aarani">Aarani</option>

<option value="ajitha">Ajitha</option>

<option value="kanul">Kanul</option>





</select><br /><br />

<input type="submit" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>
 </form>
    
</div>
  
</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>


 <style type='text/css'>
    .multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 20px;
}
 </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
$('#male').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('#female').multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.gender = [{
        name: "Male"
    }, {
        name: "Female"
    }];

    $scope.submit =function()
    {
    alert($('#male').val());
    alert($('#female').val());
    }


}
</script>

</head>
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Select your Gender</p>
    <form data-ng-submit="submit()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in gender">
            <label>{{person.name}}
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.favoriteBeatle"
                name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required="required"/>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="padding:20px">

<select id="male" multiple="multiple">

<option value="gowri">Gowri</option>

<option value="agil">Agil</option>

<option value="raju">Raju</option>

<option value="viswanath">Viswanath</option>

<option value="duruwan">Duruwan</option>



</select><br /><br />

<input type="submit" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>
<div style="padding:20px">

<select id="female" multiple="multiple">

<option value="aarani">Aarani</option>

<option value="ajitha">Ajitha</option>

<option value="kanul">Kanul</option>





</select><br /><br />

<input type="submit" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>
    </form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not like this i have given my code please check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check what value the radio button has.
You can then show only the div you want by using
ng-show="favoriteBeatle == 'Male'" or
ng-show="favoriteBeatle == 'Female'"

Then on submit check again the value of the input to display the message you want.

```
if($scope.favoriteBeatle == 'Male') {
    alert($('#male').val());
} else {
    alert($('#female').val());
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6b8vrjnb/

Comment: i need gender value also how can i get gender value with selected names

Comment: i have put in that submit function alert($scope.$parent.favoriteBeatle); its showing undefined

Comment: Don't use $scope.$parent.favoriteBeatle. It is $scope.favoriteBeatle

Comment: Because the ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope. With $parent you refer to the parent scope from inside the ngRepeat directive. This is $scope in your controller

Answer (score 2):

The Angular way would be to use two `radio` buttons, combined with a `select` and `option`s which are created via `ng-repeat`. Doing so, you can just update the name options based on the selected gender:

http://jsfiddle.net/h2rmq2zL/

Comment: after user select gender i need multiple select dropdown values with one submit button to grab all selected values

Comment: I have updated his pluncker link to support multiple selection from the dropdown values  https://jsfiddle.net/hL04y1fL/1/

Comment: thanks yar its working but checkbox and submit button missing

Comment: well, you were asking for the very problem I gave you a solution for. you were not asking for building your form.